# How to get all columns names with their index numbers in a table of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to remove certain columns of a dataframe and found it annoying typing all the column names. I would like to use columns index numbers instead of columns to remove the columns from the dataframe. The following code gives all the header names but how to get index numbers too?

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codebasics/py/master/ML/14_naive_bayes/titanic.csv")
print(df.columns)
```

Expected Output:

```
'PassengerId', 0
 'Name', 1
 'Pclass', 2
 'Sex', 3
 'Age', 4
 'SibSp', 5
 'Parch', 6
 'Ticket', 7
 'Fare', 8
 'Cabin', 9
 'Embarked', 10
 'Survived', 11
```

Answer (score 6):

Use  `pd.Series` with columns names:

```
s = pd.Series(df.columns)
print(s)
0     PassengerId
1            Name
2          Pclass
3             Sex
4             Age
5           SibSp
6           Parch
7          Ticket
8            Fare
9           Cabin
10       Embarked
11       Survived
dtype: object
```

---

Like mentioned @timgeb (thank you) is possible select by positions instead columns names:

```
df['Name']
df.iloc[:, 1]
```

---

If need remove first 2 columns use:

```
df = df.iloc[:, 2:]
```

Comment: @jezrael I need the header to be as it is. Just I need to generate a table with index numbers so that I can drop the first two columns by the following code ```df.drop(df.columns[[0, 1]], axis = 1)``` . Therefore I need index numbers of columns.

Answer (score 3):

To print both index number and column name you can use `enumerate`:

```
>>> list(enumerate(df.columns))
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I am looking for.